# Password protect a pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, pem, ssh-keygen

I'd like to SSH into my EC2 instance with a password protected pem file.  How do I password protect a pem file?  I've done this in the past but can't remember how I did it.  I took a pem file generated by AWS and ran some command on it and it generated something that looked like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,<BlahBlahBlah>

<encrypted stuff is here>

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Then when I SSH into the box, i'm specifying my password protected pem file and it asks me to enter the password before decrypting and sshing in.

I found this: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2013/05/24/improving-security-of-ssh-private-keys.html

Which tells me to use this command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N 'super secret passphrase' -f test_rsa_key
```

But the resulting encrypted file (that has the correct header i'm looking for) doesn't seem to work. I'm getting "Permission denied (publickey)." when I try to ssh using that encrypted pem file.  I am able to SSH into the box with the unencrypted pem file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is because the command you are using generates a new key pair instead of protecting your existing private key.

Try using `-p` option of `ssh-keygen`

```
ssh-keygen -p -f my_private_key
```

It will prompt you for passphrase and protect your private key.

```
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

Now if you use `my_private_key` in `ssh`, it will prompt for passphrase and it will succeed.

```
 -p      Requests changing the passphrase of a private key file instead of
         creating a new private key.  The program will prompt for the file
         containing the private key, for the old passphrase, and twice for
         the new passphrase.
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked!  Thanks.  Any ideas why my pem file from one region won't work on the other region?  I asked around and it seems that it should work.  I even selected "Use already existing pem file" and had to check the box saying yes I have the pem file.

Comment: The private keys are not shared between regions unless you uploaded the same corresponding public key in all regions.

Comment: Not shared between regions despite them giving me the option to select it?  Maybe I missed some detail that said I needed to upload the public key.  I assumed I didn't need to when they let me select it

Comment: @LampShade what is giving you the option to select it? Are you in the AWS console? Keypairs are regional. If you're launching in us-west-1 and using the EC2 launch wizard in the AWS console, then you'll only see keypairs that are relevant to us-west-1. LIkewise for other regions.

Comment: I'll send you a screenshot if I get the chance, at the very end of setting up an EC2 instance it asks to create a new pem file or select an already existing one.  Even on another region it gave me the option of selecting an already existing one (one that i created on another region).  But then it didn't work... Which was odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use the puttygen:

```
sudo apt install putty
```

And to generate your key protected, execute this:

```
puttygen KEY_PAIR_PRIVATE.pem -O private-openssh -o KEY_PAIR_PRIVATE.key -P
```

The option -P is to set a new passphrase to private key.

P.S: You will probably need to set a permission to use the key, like this:

```
sudo chmod 755 KEY_PAIR_PRIVATE.key
```

And finally you can access your aws instance safely:

```
ssh -i KEY_PAIR_PRIVATE.key ubuntu@IP_EC2_INSTANCE_OR_HOSTNAME
```